# Why is the error produced: `form` must be a single form produced by html_form()?

Tags: r, rvest

The following code produces the error: `form must be a single form produced by html_form()`

Why is this?

```
library(rvest)

account <- session("https://www.familytreedna.com/Areas/Main/Apps/SignIn/sign-in.component.html")

login = account %>% html_node("form[name=userInfoForm]") %>% html_form() %>% 
  html_form_set(
    kitNumber = "******",
    password  = "******"
  )

account = account %>% html_form_submit(login)
```

I can send the form in the way as shown below, but then the last line produces the error `x must be produced by session()` and it's not possible to jump to other urls when logged in.

What I am doing wrong?

```
login$action="https://www.familytreedna.com/Areas/Main/Apps/SignIn/sign-in.component.html"
logged_in=html_form_submit(login)

logged_in  %>% session_jump_to("https://www.familytreedna.com/groups/germany/activity-feed")
```

---

I tried this, but the login isn't successful:

```
library(rvest)
        
account = session("https://www.familytreedna.com/sign-in")
    
login = httr::GET("https://www.familytreedna.com/Areas/Main/Apps/SignIn/sign-in.component.html") %>% read_html() %>% html_node("form[name=userInfoForm]") %>% html_form() %>% 
              html_form_set(
                kitNumber = "******",
                password = "******"
              )

            login$action="https://www.familytreedna.com/Areas/Main/Apps/SignIn/sign-in.component.html"
    
res = session_submit(account, login)
```

Comment: Just use `html_form_submit(login)` to submit the form. No need to store the response since you are likely just using it to set authentication cookies. Use `account  %>% session_jump_to()` navigate after the submit is complete.

Comment: `html_form_submit()`  takes a form as a first parameter, by using `account %>% html_form_submit(login)` your session becomes the first param and that makes it complain. There's also `session_submit(x, form, submit = NULL, ...)`

Comment: `html_form_submit(login)` doesn't result in a successful login,  altough the `status_code` of the response is 200. Maybe I shouldn't load directly the form through https://www.familytreedna.com/Areas/Main/Apps/SignIn/sign-in.component.html but https://www.familytreedna.com/sign-in. Since the `request_GET()` function is drooped from `rvest`, I don't know, how to load the form via `XHR`.